# Historically accurate films about the English Civil War

Tags: england, 17th-century

Last night I saw *[Cromwell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065593/)* which is good drama but absolutely grossly inaccurate. Do you know of other good films on the subject that do more justice to the history?

Comment: I think it is an interesting question but it invites arguments and lists so it might get closed...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, but this is no different imo than asking for reference material on a topic. This kind of question would invite a list from people, and the question is more concerned with modern interpretation, than what actually happened.

Comment: I think we can edit this question to fit SE. Maybe ask what are common inaccuracies in films about the English Civil War? Then we can use examples and reference accurate films? Just a thought.

Comment: @grayQuant: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure I want to know about all possible inaccuracies - I don't know enough about the subject yet, so this might just confuse me :) :)

Comment: As a related (sub)question on reference material I am wondering which ones could have been the primary sources for [Hilary Mantel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_Mantel)'s *Cromwell Trilogy*, the first two volumes of which have been published already, and which everybody seems to laud also for accuracy. (And who knows, related film rights may have been sold already ...)